# Spark kinesis stuck on reading records after 25 days

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-kinesis

I am working on spark streaming with kinesis on EMR. For roughly 25 days my streaming was fine running for every minute and precessing around 1000 records.
I have written job in scala
Today when i looked at the master ui i saw spark was not processing any recorda and had queued 40 jobs with zero records. It was also stuck in reading records from kinesis.

Has anyone experienced this issue earlier. I am using spark 1.6